# What are the practices for load balancing web stats?

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, awstats

I'm admnistrating two servers with LAMPs which I need to set up as load balancing.

I was wondering what are the best practices to deal with statistics? my two apaches will generate each their own log file, which I need to merge and feed to awstats and I'd like to start clean.

TIA

greg

Comment: HaProxy has built in stats, and several other LBs have similar options.

Comment: Why the downvote???

Answer (score 0):

How to get all your logs converged depends on what tools you're using to work with the logs; in the case of AWStats, looks like they provide something to help you out with this, [here](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#LOADLOG).

To automate getting all the files together to merge with their tool, you can do something along the lines of setting up rsync on a cron.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is more about dis-symetry: both servers are alike, they even share the same data disks, so the raw logs are available on both side, so how to decide which computer will actually run the stats generation (which should be done only once)?